# Can I save a .png in a Foundry Code Workbook?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I'm using a Foundry Code Workbook to generate an image and then am trying to save it back into Foundry. I can generate the image fine but am struggling with saving it.

Could you please help me understand how to save a `.png` image file via a Code Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Code Workbook uses the Agg backend and saves the figure as `.png`, which you can use for reference in your attempt to save the `.png` bytes to Foundry. Specifying the backend and specifying the savefig output format will require a backend configuration change, which can be made by the Palantir Support Team.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using raw file access in python. Assuming you've selected a Python Transform Input as the input type, the following code (for matplotlib) will save a PNG to a dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
plt.show()

output = Transforms.get_output()
output_fs = output.filesystem()
plt.savefig('test.png')
img = open('test.png', 'rb').read()

with output_fs.open('png_test.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img)
    f.close()
```